# Is there a platform to develop HTML5 apps for iOS in a high school classroom environment, without Mac's?

Tags: html, ios, certificate

I am building a program at the high school where I teach that will allow us to teach some Web Development courses. One of those courses is an HTML5 App Development course. I would like the students to be able to develop apps using HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript and then load that app on their personal device and maybe share that app with friends. The apps would not be distributed through the respective app stores, this is only so they can see the fruits of their labors on their own devices and share them with friends. This would also work well for marketing this course to get more enrollment in future semesters.

Ideally I would like to use a single platform for developing these apps, regardless of the device type. For example I thought I could use PhoneGap, but recently found that Apple pulled the mobile app from their store so you have to fork and pull from github and then build the app and side load it through the QR code. However, even with this method Apple still requires any app made for iOS to be made with a signing certificate, which can only be created by using a Mac.

I don't have a Mac, I don't have a Mac lab in my classroom, is there any way to develop apps that can be installed on an iOS device without having to have a Mac to get certificates? Is there no education option that allows iOS apps to be created without going through these hoops that either require a Mac or require you use Apple software like XCode?

Am I out of luck for my students with iPhones?

Thanks

Comment: Without a Mac you will be limited to running apps from a web server; you can't have a self-contained app installed on the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile and generate your .ipa file using ReactNative and Ionic framework,  that allows you to built on there server.

But main problem arises while creating .p12 signing certification file and Uploading the .ipa file on app store or only on testflight from education purpose.
For that you need mac operating system which contain Application loader to submit your app to Apple App Store Connect.

So you have you can buy second hand mac-mini for that. Or there are some site which help you to upload your .ipa file http://www.connectuploader.com or virtually provide you mac http://www.macincloud.com.